# Order of key-value pairs in HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

If two hashmaps have exact same set of key-value pairs, will I always get data in same order while iterating on two hashmaps?

```
Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("a1","b1");
map1.put("a2","b2");
map1.put("a3","b3");
map2.put("a1","b1");
map2.put("a2","b2");
map2.put("a3","b3");

for (Map.Entry<String,String> e : map1.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(e.getKey());
}
for (Map.Entry<String,String> e : map2.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(e.getKey());
}
```

If map1's iteration look like (a1,a2,a3), will map2's iteration also be like (a1,a2,a3)?

I know that bucket index is calculated using hash of key, but I am not sure if same index will be returned always.

Comment: The order is specifically documented as undefined.

Comment: Why you don't test that using some testing framework, like JUnit?

Answer (score 5):

You can never rely on order in case of Hashmap.If you want to maintain insertion order use LinkedHashMap and for sorted order use TreeMap

Comment: In fact, any implementation of SortedMap will do the job.

Answer (score 2):

Java docs clearly say that HashMap makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, `it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time`. So, you should consider that some set of operation may gives you order map.

Answer (score -1):

The Order of key depends on the result of hashCode() function in the Keys you are inserting. But They are mostly random and consistent.

Comment: What do you mean by "random and consistent"?

Comment: It looks like the order of keys is random, but it depends on the result of hashCode(). The result of hashcode is consistent.

Comment: So _not_ random.